# How can I Access Session data from one bundle to another

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have two bundles

1. Main
2. Login

I am creating the session in one bundle and need to use the session data in another bundle.

> **How can we access the same session data in different bundles created
>   in one single bundle.**

Login Bundle Controller - Session Created:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->set('name', $user->getFname()." ".$user->getLname());
$session->set('uname', $user->getUsername());
$session->set('pwd', $user->getPassword());
```

Login - Username and Password Check

```
     if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $uname = $request->request->get('uname');
            $pwd = $request->request->get('pwd');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $repository = $em->getRepository('SimranMainBundle:Users');

            $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username'=>$uname, 'password'=>$pwd));
            if($user){
                $session = new Session();
                $session->set('name', $user->getFname()." ".$user->getLname());
                $session->set('uname', $user->getUsername());
                $session->set('pwd', $user->getPassword());
                return $this->render('SimranLoginBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $user->getFname()." ".$user->getLname(),'uname'=>$uname, 'pwd'=>$pwd));
            }
            else{
                return $this->render('SimranLoginBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => "LOGIN"));
            }
        }
```

Login Twig - index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SimranMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

Main Twig - layout.html.twig

```
{% set sessionName = session.name %}
{{ sessionName }}
```

Users Entity

Comment: The session is created in Login Bundle and session.name is working fine in its twig template.      But when using in Main Bundle's Template it is now showing anything.

Comment: @Pazi Code added in the question

Comment: Creating only a Session object, does make it a real php session. Where does the `$user` come from?

Comment: @Pazi Users is the entity created and here in this $user is fetching user details from Database from entity. Code added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should note, creating a `Session` instance means not creating a real php session. A php session is already created during fetching the request and you have to use this object.

So in your controller:

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('name', $user->getFname()." ".$user->getLname());
$session->set('uname', $user->getUsername());
$session->set('pwd', $user->getPassword());
```

And in twig the session is accessible via `app.session`.

```
{% set sessionName = app.session.get('name') %}
```